# Error installing Twitter gem on Windows

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am a new Ruby user and recent coder. I was trying to install the Twitter Gem but no luck. I am on Windows 10 and my Ruby version is 2.2.6p396, and Gem version 2.4.5.2.  Thanks ahead of time.

[image: code errors screenshot 1st page]

[image: code errors screenshot 2nd page]

Comment: if you are on Windows 10, try to work with ruby on `Windows Subsystem on Linux (WSL)` and use `RVM` for easier managing of gem versions.

Comment: Do you have the devkit installed? https://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit.html